# Why have the tag [timeline-cheapass-games] instead of renaming it [timeline]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Does anyone know a reason why we should have [timeline-cheapass-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timeline-cheapass-games) instead of changing it to [timeline](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timeline)? I see one question and it already has a wiki but not sure why the publisher should be in that tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's another game called [Timeline](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/128664/timeline) that's more widely known (nearly 1000 reviews on BoardGameGeek, sold at mass-market stores) that's not by Cheapass Games.

I can't find a BoardGameGeek page for the Cheapass Games one, and it's not easily searchable as "timeline card game" so it seems reasonable for the OP to have wanted to disambiguate.

That said, we don't seem to have any questions about the more popular one, so... not sure it matters an awful lot.

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me and sounds reasonable to me. It might not matter now but we could get some confusion later on if we switch it up at this point.

Comment: CA published Timeline game is listed at BGG here: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/7182/timeline